# update-alternatives: error: alternative link is not absolute as it should be: usr/bin/psql

Tags: 19.10, postgresql

I intend to set the psql default version and switch from version 12 to 9.6
I have typed the following line in the terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install usr/bin/psql psql usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/psql 2
```

However, the following error appears:

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative link is not absolute as it should be: usr/bin/psql
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`update-alternatives`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) works with absolute paths instead of relative paths. Replace `usr/bin/psql` and `usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/psql` with `/usr/bin/psql` and `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/psql`, i.e.,

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/psql psql /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/psql 2
```